# Drupal Calendar highlight all days in block with views

Tags: views, datetime

I have calendar showing dates (start and end dates). When I create a calendar from the views template it adds several displays. The month display shows shows all days from the start to the end day highlighted with another color. But in the block display it does not highlights those days.

Below is the month display. I need the same in the block display.

[image: Display of the month display. I need the same in the block display.]

Answer (score 0):

This is a theming issue.  [Inspect](http://cms.about.com/od/cms-basics/a/Get-The-Inspect-Element-Tool-For-Your-Browser.htm) the classes of the boxes in the calendar, you will probably find `.current-month` or something similar in there for the boxes in the month being shown.  Then edit your theme's CSS (or SASS) with:

```
.current-month{
  background-color: [color-you-desire];
}
```

Comment: I think is not the same. In the month display you can see the title across all highlighted days.

Comment: Hang on - which 'highlighting' are you talking about?  The white background on the days in the current month?  The blue numbers on days that have an event?  The event bar itself?  More detail required.

Comment: The multiday highlight. If you see in the image, the event "Test Event" displayed in all days from 17 to 22.

Comment: And what does it currently look like in the block - add it to your question.